# WOW: BfA Item level scaling in (instanced) PvP

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In the last expansion (Legion) in non-world PvP (battlegrounds, arenas) stats scaled by item level via so called "PvP templates".

Does stat scaling / PvP templates still exist in Battle for Azeroth (BfA), and if so, which stats are scaled and how?

Comment: EDIT: edited because of flags "unclear what you are asking", but do not know what is unclear can you write me in comments?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by stats scalled by iLvl? The more Ilvl you have the better the stats are on your item.

Comment: In Legion in PvP your stats was not from your gear, but ONLY from item level, just a little simple example 300il rogue - 5000agility 5000mastery, 305il rogue 5050agility, 5050 mastery, this is just example and numbers are not legit, I want to ask if it is still works this way, and if yes, I want know details about it,

Comment: How is this too broad? It asks about how item scaling in PvP works, which *can* be addressed with a single, concise answer.

Comment: @Polygnome feel free to update the question to clarify what the OP actually wants in one good question. As it currently stands, the question is pretty unclear and contains more than one question, that's why it got closed.

Comment: @dly Just because a question has multiple question marks doesn't mean its unclear or doesn't have one single, concise answer.

Comment: @dly 1. is moot, the question is specifically about instanced pvp, and the answer is pretty straight forward: PvP templates were abolished, there is no scaling in PvP except for PvE trinkets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PvP templates which scaled with average item level have been removed in BfA. The only thing that is still affected in an instanced PvP environment are PvE trinkets, which are 75% less effective.

Answer (score 1):

When I first started playing BFA, I was under the impression that pvp scaling had been removed. The damage I was dealing to enemy players seemed to be the same as what I was dealing to mobs. At some point, I found this [forum post](https://eu.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/17622573467) that claimed **the damage you deal is scaled up or down based on the item level difference between the players**.

I gave this a test myself and realize it's true. The damage you see you've done on your side is not the same damage the other player takes.

I just tested this in a duel to confirm this scaling system is still implemented. I frost shocked a 400 ilvl warrior on my 409 ilvl elemental shaman.  In my combat log, it said I did 4,431 damage. In the warrior's log, it said he received 3,870 damage.  The game compensated for our HP difference by scaling down the amount of damage I dealt to the warrior.

I don't think there are any official resources out there that explain the exact numbers behind this scaling system, but the forum post linked above seems to come close enough for a basic understanding of how it impacts the game.